# Can I use Backblaze B2 to host user image uploads? Their TOS is difficult to understand

Tags: backblaze

I want to build a simple dummy app like OfferUp where users can upload 5 images per listing.

I would normally use AWS S3 with Cloudfront to serve these images.

Can I do the same with Backblaze B2? Is this an intended usecase for the product?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yev from Backblaze here -> Yes, you can absolutely use Backblaze B2 to host images, and we have a bandwidth partnership with Cloudflare (https://help.backblaze.com/hc/en-us/articles/217666928-Using-Backblaze-B2-with-the-Cloudflare-CDN) if you also need a CDN solution.